# How to get Not Null column name in mySql database?

Tags: mysql, validation, select, input, notnull

I want to get columns name of files that defined as NOT NULL in mySql database for validation check of input before sent insert query to database.

For example:

[image]

it will return :  Fixed_activity_level, Transport_time.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `information_schema` for this task:

```
select TABLE_NAME,
       COLUMN_NAME,
       IS_NULLABLE 
from  information_schema.COLUMNS 
where TABLE_SCHEMA='your_schema_name'
and IS_NULLABLE='NO';
```

The above query will give the below output:

```
mysql> select TABLE_NAME,
    ->    COLUMN_NAME,
    ->    IS_NULLABLE
    -> from  information_schema.COLUMNS
    -> where TABLE_SCHEMA='gesti'
    -> and IS_NULLABLE='NO';

+----------------------+-------------------+-------------+
| TABLE_NAME           | COLUMN_NAME       | IS_NULLABLE |
+----------------------+-------------------+-------------+
| T1                   | id                | NO         |
| VISITS               | user_id           | NO         |
| VISITS               | user_visited      | NO         |
| addons               | created_at        | NO         |
| addons               | image             | NO         |
| addons               | name              | NO         |
| addons               | unique_identifier | NO         |
| addons               | version           | NO         |
| availabilities       | available         | NO         |
| availabilities       | created_at        | NO         |
| availabilities       | date              | NO         |
| availabilities       | type              | NO         |
| availabilities       | updated_at        | NO         |
| availabilities       | user_id           | NO         |
| breaks_mysqldump     | data              | NO         |
| breaks_mysqldump_bak | data              | NO         |
| card                 | cat_id            | NO         |
```